# Testing Database DROP failed

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a database *'alphacrn'*, and I wanted to test it by using the command **DROP**

This is the code:

```
<?php
{ // Connect and Test MySQL and specific DB (return $dbSuccess = T/F)
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";

    $dbConnected = @mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

    $dbSuccess = true;
    if ($dbConnected) {
    } else {
        echo "MySQL connection FAILED<br /><br />";
        $dbSuccess = false;
    }
}

//   Execute code ONLY if connections were successful   
if ($dbSuccess) {
    $dbName = "alphacrn";
    $drop_SQL = "DROP DATABASE " . $dbName;

    if (mysql_query($drop_SQL)) {
        echo "'DROP DATABASE " . $dbName . "' -  Successful.";
    } else {
        echo "'DROP DATABASE " . $dbName . "' - Failed.";
    }
}
?>
```

After I execute my code, I get the reply: *'DROP DATABASE alphacrn' - Failed.* 
Where did I go wrong?? The code looks clean and OK for me as far as I'm concerned. Plus the database is UP and going, nothing wrong with it...

What should I do in order to fix this error?

The mysql error:

```
echo "<br>"."<br>".mysql_error()."<br>"."<br>";

echo $drop_SQL;
```

Results in browser:

> 'DROP DATABASE alphacrn' - Failed.
>
> Can't drop database 'alphacrn'; database doesn't exist
>
> DROP DATABASE alphacrn

Comment: obligatory DONT use mysql_* for new code

Comment: Your script is echoing YOUR error message. What is the mysql_error()?

Comment: what is the mysql error saying? (not your own error text)

Comment: Why ? and what else should I use ?

Comment: Also, while at it, echo your `$drop_SQL` var and read the output. Does it read like a correctly structured query? (paste it in your question with the result from the `mysql_error()` output too)

Comment: This is what the browser returns, it doesn't show any other error. 
mysql doesn't show me any error except my own. I want to make the code work so it will show the message _'DROP DATABASE alphacrn' -  Successful._ @Tim

Comment: so, database doesn't exist... is the DB there? Are you connecting to the right place? Does the var in your code match the DB name?

Comment: OMG... I accidentally wrote in the DB name: alphacrn and the DB's name from phpMyadmin was alphacrM not 'N' (at the end).

Amazing how one letter can ruin everything

Comment: meh it happens. Just make sure you echo out your vars when scratching your head. you must verify 100% what your script is actually doing, and never presume what you believe it to be doing must be right :)

Comment: hah my answer was correct....

Comment: Please don't put `[solved]` in the title. Answer your question in the answer section below. You can indicate that your question is solved by accepting an answer. Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code is working, there's no problem with it, I tried it a few seconds ago.

Maybe the following is your problem:
You haven't got in the SQL the alphacrn database and it can't delete it.
Or your user hasn't got permission to drop database.

If you want to know which one is the problem, see it manually or use `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 0):

@James managed to answer my question properly.
I checked both my variable and my database name and when I got in the phpMyadmin the database name wasn't corresponding with the one from my PHP command.

I did a one letter typo (DB name = 'alphacrM' not 'alphacrN') which caused the code failure.